# HTML5 How to get first frame of a video

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, video

I am trying to get the first frame of a video in order to put it in a canvas, using this code but the canvas remains empty.

```
video.addEventListener("canplay",function () {
    var $this = this;
    console.log("canplay");
    console.log(video.readyState);
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage($this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
});
```

I also use this code to mirror the video in a canvas and it works.

```
video.addEventListener('play', function() {
    var $this = this;
    (function loop() {
        if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended) {
            context.save();
            context.scale(-1, 1);
            context.drawImage($this, 0, 0, mCanvas.width*-1, mCanvas.height);
            context.restore();
            setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30); // drawing at 30fps
        }
    })();
}, 0);
```

How can I get the first frame of the video? Morevoer I have the possibility to change the URL dynamically: what should I do to get the first frame of the new video?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? Fully transparent? The console.log calls are triggered? Do you have error messages in the console? Did you do anyhting else to this canvas anywhere else? Could you set up a live example? You can use some [video files](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm) from wikimedia and create a live snippet by clicking <> button in the editor.